# Function in javascript to find and locate text which is located in a TAB inside an accordion through a text box search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

``I have an HTML page where i have multiple accordions. In each accordion again are some tabs.

Now, I need to write a function through which an user can enter a keyword in a text box and search.

The search should be something similar to query search where he can able to locate the text he typed in search box.

I can able to populate the text suggestions according to the query user is typing.

[image: Output should be like this]

Please go through the HTML code here

```
<div id="centerContent">
<div class="myaccordion">
    <h2 id="dailyReportsTab">
        <font color="white"
            style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Administrative Daily Reports</font>
    </h2>
    <div class="hidden_div">
        <div>
            <ul class="tabs-menu">
                <li class="current" style="margin-left: 0px;"><a href="#headSummaryTab">HeadWise Summary Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#headWiseCashBookTab">HeadWise Cashbook Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#cashBookTab">Cashbook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#thriftcashBookTab">GeneralCashbook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#zoneWiseReceiptPrinting">Zone Wise Receipt Printing</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab" id="dailyReportsPanel"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2 id="auditReportsTab">
        <font color="white" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Audit Reports</font>
    </h2>
    <div class="hidden_div">
        <div>
            <ul class="tabs-menu">
                <li class="current" style="margin-left: 0px;"><a href="#hbBtwnDatesTab">Heads Balance Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#groupwiseHbTab">Group wise Heads Balance Report</a></li>
                <li class="cashAtBankTab"><a href="#cashAtbankTab">Cash At Banks Report</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab" id="auditReportsPanel"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <h2  id="loanReportsTab">
        <font color="white" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Loan Reports</font>
    </h2>
    <div class="hidden_div">
        <div>
            <ul class="tabs-menu">
                <li><a href="#loanApplicationReport">Loan Application Report</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab" id="loanReportsPanel"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2 id="recoveyMenuTab">
        <font color="white"
            style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Monthly Recovery Report</font>
    </h2>
    <div style="background: #FFFFFF; width: 976px; height: auto; border: 1px solid #0DABFF; border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; padding: 10px 10px;">
        <div>
            <ul class="tabs-menu">
                <li class="current" style="margin-left: 0px;"><a href="#psmonthlyRecoveryTab">Monthly Recovery Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#zoneWisePartialAndDueMembersReport">Zonewise Partial And Due members Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#totalDueAndPartialMembersInSociety">Total Due And Partial Members In Society</a></li>
                <li><a href="#PSWiseBifurCationReport">PS Wise Bifurcation Report</a></li>

            </ul>
            <div class="tab" id="psRecoveryReportsPanel"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <h2 id="accountingReport">
        <font color="white" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Accounting Reports</font>
    </h2>
     <div class="hidden_div">
        <div>
            <ul class="tabs-menu">
                <li><a href="#receiptsNChargingTab">Receipts and Charging Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#trailBalTab">Trail Balance Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#profitAndLossTab">Profit And Loss Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#approvedNeftTrxns">Approved Neft Transactions Report</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab" id="accountingReportPanel"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <h2 id="financialYearReportsTab">
        <font color="white"
            style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Financial Year Reports</font>
    </h2>
    <div class="hidden_div">
        <div>
            <ul class="tabs-menu">
                <li><a href="#thriftInterestReportsTab">Thrift Interest Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#electionRelatedReportTab">Election Related Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#scholarshipReportTab">Scholarship Report</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab" id="financialReportsPanel"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Please go through the jQuery code here.

```
"onChangeOfReportsSearch": function() {
  jQuery(".reportsSearch").on("change", function() {
  var searchBoxValue = jQuery(".reportsSearch").val();
  var NoOfAnchorTagsInDiv = $(".myaccordion").find('li a').length;
  for (i = 0; i <= NoOfAnchorTagsInDiv - 1; i++) {
    if (($(".myaccordion").find('li a')[i].text == searchBoxValue); {
      //how to open tab in accordian
    }
  }

  });
}
```

Please Help :)

Comment: Not sure about what the question is... precisely. --- There's only HTML posted. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you want to search throught the tab titles... And when there is a match, open the relevant accordeon and tab. -- This sure is possible. But... If you don't want to even try, hire someone.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I developed all the web portal by myself. Im not much into js so i had to rely on 3rd parties to get my work done. you completely understood my question but doesn't mean you still know the answer.i don`t want rely upon somebody who doesn't even know the spelling of accordion.I found my solution thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: So is it "accordion" or "accordian" ? I wrote it in french because I typed my comment quite fast. At least, me, I know how to format a question on SO. There is a big yellow square on th right side explaining how to format, when you edit a question.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i don't have the time to argue with you.if know the solution means please help me or else stay out of it don't waste your's time and mine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to search the tabs' titles for the search term entered in the search box, right?

**Updated code:**

```
function search( term ) {
    // get all tabs in .myaccordion
    var $tabs = $('.myaccordion .tabs-menu li');

    $tabs.each(functions( item ){
        if ( $( item ).find( 'a' ).text() == term ) {
            // search term found, tab's title == term

            // let's highlight that tab's text
            $( item ).find( 'a' ).addClass( 'highlight' );

            // if you want to expand the accordion where this tab lies
            // well, I am not sure how your accordion works
            // but try to find the closest parent, in your case, it can be
            // $( item ).closest( '.hidden_div' );
            // and then expand it,

            // tab to expand
            var $tab = $( item ).closest( '.hidden_div' ).prev();

            // find index of this tab
            var index = $('.myaccordion > h2').index( $tab );

            // now activate/expand the tab
            $('.myaccordion').accordion( 'option', 'active', index );

        }
    });
}
```

CSS for `.highlight`

```
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Now to call this function, there are a number of ways.
1. Event listener

```
$('#your_search_box').on('input',function(e){
    search( $(this).val() );
});
```

2. Bind in HTML

```
<input id="your_search_box" onchange="search(this.val);" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahmadh i was unable to open a tab based on text given in a text box could you please help me?here is my js `"onChangeOfReportsSearch": function() {
 jQuery(".reportsSearch").on("change", function() {
         var searchBoxValue = jQuery(".reportsSearch").val();
         var NoOfAnchorTagsInDiv = $(".myaccordion").find('li a').length;
         for (i = 0; i <= NoOfAnchorTagsInDiv - 1; i++) {
             if (($(".myaccordion").find('li a')[i].text == searchBoxValue); {
                     //how to open tab in accordian
                 }
             }

         });
 }`

Comment: If you could get me link to the portal, if live or a screenshot of .myaccordion in devtools while one of the tab is being expanded, maybe I can help then.

Comment: @SivaShankar Note that I didn't test most of the code, so please test and debug.

Comment: `var $tab = $( item ).closest( '.hidden_div' ).previous();`

Comment: in browser console iam getting .previous();is not a fonction

Comment: @SivaShankar It is `.prev()`, please update your code. I forgot to make the correction.

Comment: :in my browser console i am getting prev() is  not a function

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of the final code and screenshot of your browser error? Also, HTML of the `.myaccordion`

Comment: here is my js`var NoOfAnchorTagsInDiv = $(".myaccordion").find('li a').length;
    for(i=0;i<=NoOfAnchorTagsInDiv-1;i++){
     if(($(".myaccordion").find('li a')[i].text) == searchBoxValue){
                        console.log($(".myaccordion").find('li a')[i].text);
                        var tab = $(".myaccordion").find('li a')[i].closest( 'div.hidden_div' ).prev();
                        var index = $('.myaccordion > h2').index( tab );
                        $('.myaccordion').accordion( 'option', 'active', index );

     }
    }`

Comment: Do you see an error regarding `.text`? Please update in your code `.text` to `.text()`

Comment: Okay. So, the issue is with your selection of nth-item in the array. You're using `$(".myaccordion").find('li a')[i]` which returns DOM element and it is no more a jQuery object. Change all your `[i]` and replace with `.eq(i)` making the above code as `$(".myaccordion").find('li a').eq(i)`

Comment: HTML code is as same as in the question  i am sending the Screen shots of js and browser console [link](http://i.imgur.com/jTo9Wlt.png)   (http://i.imgur.com/zJ6lmKo.png)     (http://i.imgur.com/Mt7A5ls.png)

Comment: Just replace `.text` with `.text()` and `[i]` with `.eq(i)` and everything will be fine.

Comment: Ahmad : inner tab is not opening could you please help me?

Comment: Can you setup the site on a live URL so I can provide you exact code?

Comment: i got the solution thank very much for your support :)

Comment: could you please give me your mail Id?

Comment: I am afraid I can't do that. If you have any questions, tag it correctly and hopefully I'll find it.